# Python: How to quickly upload to Google BigQuery?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I track about 250,000 time-series files which I have uploaded to `Google bigquery`. Every day each time-series has about 200 new rows that should downloaded through some `API` and then uploaded to `bigquery`. I have set up a python script that first connects to `Google BigQuery` to get the last dates of each time-series, then the script uses multiprocessing to create 10 processes that each connect to some `API` and download the missing data. After the download, which takes about 2 seconds, I need to get the data into `BigQuery`. I currently use the `pandas` function named `to_gbq` to upload the data and I timed how long it takes to upload, here are the results:

```
  1,000 rows takes  45 seconds
 10,000 rows takes  52 seconds
100,000 rows takes 128 seconds
```

so based on that I am thinking of appending to a big `dataframe` in memory and then using `to_gbq` when the `dataframe` reaches 100,000 rows.I have been advised to find a solution which does not depend on memory at all, and just uploads that data to `bigquery` as soon as it is downloaded. What is a good way to tackle this problem?

I am appending all of the downloaded data to the same table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) for this problem. It's already a distributed processing framework designed to handle this type of ETL task.

Going through this [example](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/) will give you a good grasp on how to use it. You could schedule your pipeline execution using [Dataflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview) or [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/) as well.